# Galaxy S3: I747UCUEMJB upgrade - baseband unknown

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3, custom-roms, mobile-network

Last night I updated my Galaxy S3 from Cyanogenmod 9 to CM 11. One of the steps was to upgrade the bootloader. Everything went fine, and I'm now on `CM 11-2014-06-02-d2lte`.

The problem: can't connect to mobile network.

Settings > About Phone:

```
Model number: SAMSUNG-SGH-I747
Baseband version: Unknown
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: We do need more information. Which carrier, and exact model do you have?

Comment: Carrier = AT&T. Model Galaxy S3 SGH-I747